# Changing object element within json

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I have JSON like this

```
{
    "amounts": [
        {
            "tid": 7072,
            "amount": 10000,
            "currency": "USD"
        },
        {
            "tid": 7072,
            "amount": 4000,
            "currency": "USD"
        }
    ],
    "status": 0,
    "errorCode": 0
}
```

I need to retrieve amount  value from this JSON and to divide for example in 10. After that i would like to replace amount value in original json . How can i do this? I am using .Net json tools like NEwtonsoft json.

Comment: i think you json is wrong:: it should be like this:: `{"amounts":[{"tid":7072,"amount":10000,"currency":"USD"},{"tid":7072,"amount":4000,"currency":"USD"}],"status":0,"errorCode":0}`

Comment: which object's amount do you want to retrieve 1st or 2nd? and after retrieved you have to divide it by 10 right?

Comment: Yes. I Wanta retreive both.

Comment: Deserialize it, process objects and serialize again.

Comment: simply run a `for` loop in `data['amounts']`  and for each iteration of the loop you can `loop_variable['amount'] = loop_variable['amount']/10`

Comment: Generate class via https://app.quicktype.io/#l=cs&r=json2csharp use FromJson, change and ToJson, enjoy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private string DivideAmounts(string str, int denominator)
    {
        var obj = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(str);
        foreach (var amount in obj["amounts"])
        {
            var value = amount.Value<int>("amount");
            var newValue = value / denominator;
            amount["amount"] = newValue;
        }
        return obj.ToString();
    }
```

Using Newtonsoft.Json.
Add check of argument "denominator" to avoid divide-by-zero error.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following [tool](https://app.quicktype.io/#l=cs&r=json2csharp) to generate classes:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp11
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var js = "{\"amounts\": [ { \"tid\": 7072, \"amount\": 10000, \"currency\": \"USD\"        },        {            \"tid\": 7072,            \"amount\": 4000,            \"currency\": \"USD\"        }    ],    \"status\": 0,    \"errorCode\": 0}";
            var obj = Welcome.FromJson(js);
            for (int i = 0; i < obj.Amounts.Length; i++)
            {
                obj.Amounts[i].AmountAmount /= 10;
            }
            var newjs = Serialize.ToJson(obj);
            Console.WriteLine(newjs);
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }

    public partial class Welcome
    {
        [JsonProperty("amounts")]
        public Amount[] Amounts { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("status")]
        public long Status { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("errorCode")]
        public long ErrorCode { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Amount
    {
        [JsonProperty("tid")]
        public long Tid { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("amount")]
        public long AmountAmount { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("currency")]
        public string Currency { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Welcome
    {
        public static Welcome FromJson(string json) => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Welcome>(json, Converter.Settings);
    }



    public static class Converter
    {
        public static readonly JsonSerializerSettings Settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore,
            DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None,
            Converters = {
                new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeStyles = DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal }
            },
        };
    }

    public static class Serialize
    {
        public static string ToJson(this Welcome self)
        {
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(self, Converter.Settings);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generate quicktype from [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) like

```
public class Amount
{
    public int tid { get; set; }
    public int amount { get; set; }
    public string currency { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Amount> amounts { get; set; }
    public int status { get; set; }
    public int errorCode { get; set; }
}
```

1) First of all deserialize your json `string` to `RootObject`

2) Iterate over on `amounts` property in `RootObject`.

3) Make arithmetic operation on your amount like divide by 10.

4) Serialize again your `RootObject`.

Here I create a console app for your demonstration purpose that shows how above steps will be executed.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string inputJson = @"{'amounts':[{'tid':7072,'amount':10000,'currency':'USD'},{'tid':7072,'amount':4000,'currency':'USD'}],'status':0,'errorCode':0}";

        RootObject rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(inputJson);

        foreach (var item in rootObject.amounts)
        {
            item.amount = item.amount / 10;
        }

        //OR you can do it with shorter version of foreach
        //rootObject.amounts.ForEach(x => x.amount = x.amount / 10);

        string outputJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rootObject);

        Console.WriteLine(outputJson);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]